# What does `android.accounts.Account.type` reference?

Tags: java, android, testing

In the Google Play Developer console, I'm getting warnings in the Pre-Launch tests mentioning:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.accounts.Account.type' on a null object reference`

The app never crashes and the test succeeds, but the warning is still there in details of the test. What is `android.accounts.Account` and how can I make sure it doesn't have issues?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html)? It's hard to say any more as we've no idea whether your code *does* anything with accounts, or whether the developer console shows you any more information, like a stack trace...

Comment: I'm getting this too, I think it could be because of out of date play services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same issue occurs with my pre-launch reports from google developer console. If you look closer into the log file provided, you will see that sometimes a test device is not set up correctly and throws this exception when setting up for a video to be taken instead of a screenshot (this feature was enabled in android 5.x). Dont worry about it. I do neglect these errors regularily.

Answer (score 0):

have you put permission in Manifest ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```